# How to return all rows but change count when a condition is satisfied-postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would appreciate any help or resources to solve this query!

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output. So many conditions, I am not sure if I got all of this correctly...

Answer (score 0):

To get all directors, replace the `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN` everywhere (you need to move the `WHERE` conditions into the join condition to avoid removing NULL rows after the join). Then use `count(act.id)` to count the actors. This will automatically skip all NULL values, so you don't have to worry about them. Actors will be counted multiple times if they act in more than one picture. If you want to avoid that, use `count(DISTINCT act.id)`.

Comment: Furthermore, IMO, you need to move the WHERE condition into the join condition to avoid removing the NULL directors after the join.

Comment: That is very true.

Answer (score 0):

[step-by-step demo:dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=291dc8307bfa2da118b9d7a5640db56b)

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.fname,
    d.lname,
    COUNT(DISTINCT act.id)                                   -- 3
FROM director d
LEFT JOIN movie_director mdir ON mdir.did = d.id             -- 1
LEFT JOIN casts cas ON cas.mid = mdir.mid
LEFT JOIN actor act ON cas.aid = act.id
    AND d.lname = act.lname AND d.fname != act.fname         -- 2
GROUP BY d.id, d.fname, d.lname
```

1. `LEFT` instead of `INNER` join for joining to keep the directors which do not fulfill the condition
2. Move your filter `WHERE` condition into the join condition. In your way, the join will be done and afterwards the filter removes all directors without required actors. If you move it into the join condition, the `LEFT` join ensure to keep these `director`s nonetheless
3. `DISTINCT` in `COUNT()` aggregate returns the actor only once. Important: You counted the directors ids, not the actors. But you are interested in the actor!

Comment: @Guest1 Did this help? Please don't forget to UPVOTE every answer which helped in any way. This honors the time and effort the replier invested into your problem. If one specific answer solves your problem completely, please ACCEPT it addionally to close the question.